# IDA + Assembler редактирование

Tags: ассемблер, ida-pro

Есть код:

```
.text:080B1176                 push    ebp
.text:080B1177                 mov     ebp, esp
.text:080B1179                 mov     edx, [ebp+8]
.text:080B117C                 mov     eax, [ebp+8]
.text:080B117F                 mov     eax, [eax+0AA0h]
.text:080B1185                 add     eax, [edx+0A9Ch]
.text:080B118B                 leave
.text:080B118C                 retn
```

Как его можно изменить в иде так, чтобы функция возвращала 0 или 1000?

Answer (score 3):

ИДА для редактирования не предназначена. Чтобы функция возвращала например 1000, нужно команды

```
mov eax, [eax+0AA0h]
add eax, [edx+0A9Ch]
```

заменить на:

```
mov eax, 1000
; "лишние" байты забить командой nop
```

Отредактировать можно например в [HIEW](http://www.hiew.ru/) или [HT Editor](http://hte.sourceforge.net/) (рекомендую последний)

Comment: Спасибо сейчас попробую.